# How to run command on startup?

Tags: pulumi

How does one instruct Pulumi to execute one or more commands on a remote host?

The equivalent Terraform command is `remote-exec`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pulumi currently doesn't support `remote-exec`-like provisioners but they are on the roadmap (see https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues/1691).

For now, I'd recommend using the cloud-init userdata functionality of the various providers as in this [AWS EC2 example](https://github.com/pulumi/examples/blob/1983bd4292265f9628e858b6105b61aaa02bfe4e/aws-js-webserver/index.js#L36).

Comment: Is it possible to execute a script after the instance is already up? The `userdata` script cannot reference properties of the `server` variable because the latter depends on the former.

Comment: Not currently, no. That would require the roadmap item I mentioned (provisioners).

Though depending on what you're trying to do, this may still be done using userdata. Amazon's metadata service exposes instance properties to scripts/apps running on the instance - so you could potentially use values from that in your scripts. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html for more info.

Comment: It's now possible with https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/command

Answer (score 4):

Pulumi supports this with [the Command package](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/command/) as of 2021-12-31: https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues/99#issuecomment-1003445058